# does life make or break?

Tags: molecular-biology, digestive-system, systems-biology, biosynthesis

Ok, this question seems like it may be impossible to answer, but would be interesting to see if anyone has an idea.

Throughout the course of a human life, do we make more molecular bonds than we break, or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Metabolism ≈ Anabolism + catabolism**

[Metabolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolism) is the set of all chemical reactions happening inside a living body. These reactions can either breaks down big molecules and build up big molecules. The set of reactions the breaks down big molecules is called [catabolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catabolism). The set of reactions that build up big molecules is called [anabolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabolism).

**Energy**

Generally speaking, anabolism cost energy and catabolism yield energy. The molecule that is directly used to transfer this energy is [Adenosine triphosphate (ATP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate).

Any energy transfer is coupled with some loss of energy from the system (see [Energy conversion efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_conversion_efficiency)).

**Entropy**

For any chemical reactions, there is always an overall increase of entropy. As a consequence, a living organism increases the entropy in its surrounding. In other words, it breaks more than it builds.

**Your question**

> does life make or break?

Life does both! But on average, it mainly breaks things up (just like any other chemical reaction).

**Want to learn more?**

The concepts of energy and entropy are studied in physics and chemistry but not so much in biology. I cannot really give you a good source of information.

Khan Academy offers a very good introductory course on metabolism ([here](https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/mcat/biomolecules/overview-metabolism/v/overview-of-metabolism-anabolism-and-catabolism)), you should have a look!

Comment: that's a great answer, thankyou. But if the breaking of molecular bonds is endothermic, and life 'mainly breaks things up', does that mean life is negative entropy? http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2010/10/28/the-marriage-may-be-bad-but-the-divorce-still-costs-money/

Comment: My guess would be that, as complex organisms, we make more complex molecules than we break ---> net exothermic ---> entropy